# Media-converting software suitable for Chromecast

Tags: media-converter, raspberry-pi

What options do I have to convert media files (mostly `.avi` files) to the formats supported for Chromecast?

Specifically, this [Chromecast FAQ](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2563143) recommends:

```
Encode in H.264 Codec MP4. Keep the Video Bitrate lower than 4000
```

I'm ok with any software on Linux / Windows, but preferably:

- takes command line / has batch processing feature, so that the process can be automated
- not requires much CPU power (ideally can run on a Raspberry Pi)

Comment: I'd note that encoding *is* generally heavy, even on a PC. The tradeoff for not needing power is taking time - I've had encodes take between 2x realtime (on a c2d) to maybe 1/6th realtime using quicksync. Your best option is really to encode elsewhere and use the raspi as a server. From my own experiences the raspi can't really handle a full 100mbps connection either.

Comment: Jeff, in case you need to make a tradeoff, do you care more about CPU power or about quality?

Comment: @nicolas i am ok with some quality loss, if it's fast enough on raspberry pi

Comment: @JourneymanGeek thanks for the suggestion. i'm doing the encoding outside the raspberry pi. see my comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/):

- Free and open-source
- Cross platform and can be complied for [RaspberryPi](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/RaspberryPi)
- Is CLI so you can batch.

Comment: i end up doing the encoding on a separate machine. for command i use the "CRF Example" in [this guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264): `ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a copy output.mkv`

Comment: an alternative command is listed in [this superuser answer](http://superuser.com/questions/724204/optimum-parameters-for-ffmpeg-to-keep-file-size/726318#726318)